# Vert.x production use cases and production stability, pros and cons

Tags: java, reactive-programming, vert.x, production-environment, vert.x-webclient

Hi am thinking to give vert.x Eclipse project a try. I have used reactive programming using spring web flux. But vert.x is sounding interesting to me. But before starting and investing time i am looking answer for following question.

1. Why vert.x, from the documentation i can see it is easy to use( i have seen some code snippets) It seems easy to use compare to spring web flux/
2. I am looking for a new tech skills that scale and efficient. So if someone is using vert.x in production can you share benchmarking?
3. What are production use cases?

Anyone can please help in this?

Comment: The [intro](https://vertx.io/introduction-to-vertx-and-reactive/) page should answer your question about the value proposition of Vert.x. About benchmarking, take a look at [Techempower](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r21&l=zik0vz-6bj&test=composite). At the bottom of the vertx.io page, there's a _Who’s using_ section. Vert.x is versatile and can be used to develop applications webapps, IoT, protocol translators, websockets bridges... list goes on.